# How to create a slanted header without messing up background image

Tags: html, css

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J80ts.png)**Hello im a newbie at at web development so any tips would be most helpful, im attempting to create a slanted style header, any ideas on how I can slant my header on the bottom without my background image repeats even though I specified no repeat.The current solution I have doesn't seem to be working, and it's distorting the background image. id be grateful for any advice and knowledge on this situation**

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:1.125rem;
}
.container{
    width:90%;
    max-width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
header{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:20rem;
    background:rgba(0, 0, .39);
    padding:1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("Lake-Mountains.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 }
 header:after{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:'';
    background: inherit;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewY(4deg);
 }

/*Typography */
 .subtitle{
    color:rgb(255, 166, 0);
    margin:0;
    font-size:.75rem;
}

 h1{
    color:rgb(255, 166, 0);
    font-size:2rem;
    margin:0;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgb(255, 196, 0);
    font-size:1.1rem;
}
/*navbar */

nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    padding: 0;
    

}
li{
    margin-top:.5rem;
}

.navbar-box{
    background-color:rgba(60, 84, 95, 0.6);
    padding:-10em;
    border:rgb(229, 236, 118) 2px solid;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction:column;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus{
    color:rgb(7, 185, 255);
}
.current:hover{
    color:rgb(143, 180, 248);
}
@media screen and (min-width:795px){

    header{
        background-size:100%;
        max-width:60%;
        width: 70%;
        height: 70%;
        margin: 40px auto;

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<header>
    <div class="container navbar-box">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Mosquito Bros</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Walla Walla County Based Company</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a>About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<body>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position:abslute` is that a typo?

Comment: What do you mean with "without my background image being distorted"? We can't see the image since its url is not absolute. From the CSS docs for [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size): "**cover**: Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains."

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your css

Change

```
 header:after{
    position:abslute;
    ...
 }
```

to

```
 header:after{
    position:absolute;
    ...
 }
```